# How to avoid the creation of unwanted logstash index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I could see that some junk indexs are generating with the normal in logstash. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like because Weblogic is doing log buffering, logstash is seeing a partial line (201) and discarding it and then seeing the remainder of the line later.  You could try setting the log buffer size in WL to 0 to see if that fixes the problem or adjust your pattern so that it's looking for a 4 digit year explicitly... that might miss log entries though.

Comment: Right now in logstash config , I am using pattern DATESTAMP for multiline.